# How to use Shiro to map permissions from an Active Directory group policy

Tags: active-directory, shiro, rbac

Several of the questions that I've reviewed on this subject seem to assume that the reader understands what it is I'm going to ask here.  For example, these two:

[Resource Based Access Control vs Role Based Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435219/resource-based-access-control-vs-role-based-access-control?lq=1)

[How do concepts of User (UserAccount) and Realm relate in Apache Shiro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124192/how-do-concepts-of-user-useraccount-and-realm-relate-in-apache-shiro)

My question is more basic:  How does one connect a Shiro Realm to a back end permission construct like Active Directory?  In other words if I have code like this:

```
if (user.isPermitted("projectReport:view:12345")) {
    //show the project report button
} else {
    //don't show the button
}
```

How is the interface to the AD established and controlled? Likewise, if the back-end permission repository is LDAP.

Pointers to appropriate documentation (which I've looked for unsuccessfully) much appreciated.
Thanks